# FastMM LogAllocatedBlocksToFile in ShareMM

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I have a bunch of EXEs dynamically loading another bunch of DLLs, most of them exposing COM objects.

Now I'm trying to debug one of these DLLs using one of the EXEs.

All projects are compiled with latest FastMM4 (4.991) with ShareMM and such, in fulldebugmode.

There is a routine that has some weird object creation/assign/destruction behavior so I was thinking to log those to catch the objects destroyed by it which were not created by it.

I use SetMMLogFileName('before') and LogAllocatedBlocksToFile(0, 0); to have a snapshot of whatever exists before the routine starts it's work.

Then do a PushALlocationGroup(1) and after the routine finishes, I do similar calls as above.

The problem is, nothing is logged. That kind of makes sense since the routine is executed in the DLL and the main MM is initialized by the EXE (already confirmed this in debugging).

So basically I need to make the log allocation blocks routines in FastMM share-aware. I looked over the code but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Anyone did this already or has some pointers to get me started?

Thanks.